# SQLAlchemy many-to-many relationship access over multiple tables

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have User, Role and Project Tables, they look something like this:

```py
Project(id: int, name: str, access_roles: list[Role])
Role(id: int, name: str)
User(id: int, name: str, roles: list[Role])
```

I need to get all projects that have any role that user has.

```py
# user is given
projects = []
all_projects = Project.query.all()
for project in all_projects:
    if any(role in project.access_roles for role in user.roles):
        projects.append(project)
return projects
```

How can I get the projects without iterating over all of them?

I tried this, but got an error.

```py
return Project.query.where(Project.access_roles.in_(user.roles)).all()
# NotImplementedError: in_() not yet supported for relationships
```

Is this even possible? What am I doing wrong?